# How to call typescript function from JQuery datepicker select

Tags: angular, typescript

How do i call updateFunc from select below.

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
     onSelect: function (selected, evnt) {
        this.updateFunc(evnt);
      }
    });
}

updateFunc(evnt: any) {
    alert("hi");
}
```

This is not working, i should use => to call another function, this.function wont work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answered your own question but yes, instead of writing onSelect using the `function` tag, use an arrow function, which will preserve the scope of this to where it was called from.  When you use the `function` keyword, you're creating a new scope, where `this` will refer to variables inside that function's scope.

Arrow functions are the way to go here, but some older approaches before those came along would be using `.bind(this)` or doing something like this before you create that function.

```
let self = this;  // create a reference to 'this' above isolate scope.
onSelect: function(selected,evnt){
    self.updateFunc(event)
};
```

With arrow functions you shouldn't have to do this, just do:

```
onSelect:(selected,evnt) => { //arrow function passes the this into the new scope
    this.updateFunc(event)
}
```

Comment: Thats perfect. Thank you, i tried with arrow but i forgot to remove function keyword after onSelect. Thanks again